# How to add new button for all job pages

Tags: jenkins, button, jenkins-pipeline

How to add new Button at All job pages?

I want to show Run button at job page and when click button show build with parameter page as a popup form like a blue ocean.

Please someone can tell me how to do or reference site?

Thank you so much

Comment: If you've installed the [Build With Parameters](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-with-parameters/) plugin, then the button should be on the LH side already, replacing the "Build" button. It brings up another page with the parameters to select and a Build button.

Comment: I already using that...I want to run with only one page like a Blue ocean GUI

Comment: It's a two step process: you are choosing to build (as opposed to configure / status, etc), then you supply / choose the build parameters, then click Build. Otherwise, rewrite the BwP plugin then (and core?) to make that the default page. Also, Blue Ocean is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below plugin:

Build parameterised plugin

reference link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBAaxv49_tM

Comment: Actually i want is build with parameter do at one page.. parameterised plugin can add only parameter to build for that need to click build with parameter button and put parameter at another page... My question is how to add button in job page GUI customize... Thank u for your answer